# Ajax fails 5% of time, response is "error"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using jQuery to handle Ajax-calls.
I've noticed that, about 5% off the time, the ajax call fails. To make sure I get a good understanding of what's going wrong, I use this code:

```
$.ajax({

    type:'POST',
    url:'somepage.php',
    data:{somedata:somedata},
    success:function (data) {

        var IS_JSON = true;

        try
         {
            var newdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         }
         catch(err)
         {
           IS_JSON = false;
         }

         if(IS_JSON)
         {
            //this is the part where a correct response is handled

         }
         else
         {
          //In case somepage.php gives a php-error, I put the exact error (=data) in the error-table at error.php.
         window.location = "error.php?errorstring="+data;
         }


    },
    error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //In case the ajax errors, I store the response (timeout, error, ...) in the database at error.php
        window.location = "error.php?errorstring="+textStatus;

    }

});
```

"Good" responses contain JSON, which I parse. If it's not JSON (for example just raw text from an php error) I don't try to parse it, but store the error in my database.

I would understand errors containing php errors that occured on somepage.php (since it's quiet a large page), but I'm supprised that the main errors I get, are errors of the ajax failing. The response data is just "error".

Anyone knows what the cause could be? **What causes ajax-calls to fail**? It's *not a timeout*, and it's also nothing like that somepage.php wasn't found or something. It's also not an error on somepage.php, since in that case, the Ajax-call would be successful, and the php-error would be logged in my database.

Edit: I used [this](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/) obfuscator to make the script a little harder to read... Don't know if this could be causing the errors...

Comment: ajax 'error' can be cause by internal server errors, such as the ones from missing curly braces. have you been able to identify a difference in the params sent with the ajax call on those 5%?

Comment: This is most likely something in your PHP script, not in AJAX.  Try adding console.log(data); as the first line of your response function.  That way, you can see what PHP is actually echoing (your PHP script might be echoing an error that looks like an AJAX failure.

Comment: It happens a lot with requests from Apple stuff for me too.

Comment: @Michael Do you mean my PHP would echo "error"? I've thought about that, but double checked it, and I never echo "error". PHP-errors itself would also be different, since they start with "Warning" or "Fatal error" or ... , not just "error".

Comment: Sometimes PHP will have an internal failure and not "echo" anything, but rather print the error (depending on your PHP.ini settings for error_reporting...mine is set to error_reporting = E_STRICT).  I've starting using this method a lot because you can see which line your PHP code is failing on in the console in the developer tab (F12)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: the data being sent are just some number. However, the PHP-script does a lot of user-specific things, since it's a Facebook app. But should all of this fail, I the PHP-script would simply echo the error, and the ajax-call would be succesful.

Comment: We (and you) need more information to debug this issue. we need to know "why" it fails. You can get more information on why by inspecting the xhr that is returned to the error callback. If you can't recreate the issue in your own environment, or send yourself enough information to figure out the why, this is going to be near impossible to debug and know for sure that anything was fixed.

Comment: @binoculars unless the php script have an fatal or parse error, which are not that uncommon... like a dynamic sql query trying to select a non existing field

Comment: @Michael it never happend to me, but to other users. The script executed more then 50.000 times by now, so you must be pretty "lucky" to see it fail, so I can't use F12.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: aren't fatal errors just echo'd by php? Info: I'm not using a dynamicaly formed sql query.

Comment: @binoculars Possibly, but if your php also returns an error header, such as 500, jquery would see it as a failure.

Comment: @KevinB Is there any way I can check whether or not this was the case (error header)?

Comment: Yes, by looking at the xhr. There's also a status code parameter passed to .fail and the error callback, however it's better to look directly at the xhr.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not familiar with xhr, but I'll store the xhr. Now I just have to wait until one of my users hits an error...

Comment: @KevinB Tried it with a dummy script, but the xhr isn't just a string, so I just get "[object] [Object]". How can I extract the relevant data for this issue?

Comment: You should use firebug or chromedev tools, use the network tab and do the ajax call. Look at the status code and the raw response from the server

Comment: I'm not able to recreate the issue, so I can't use dev tools. I have to find a way to store the raw response.

Comment: you can stringify it: `JSON.stringify(thexhr)`. Note however that if the browser doesn't support JSON.stringify, you'll have to add it.

Comment: OK, so on a dummy script, in which I point it to a non-existing PHP-file, I get `{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}` . Will this line of information be sufficient to know what's causing the error? If so, I could just store this string in my database, and wait for a user to hit the error...

Comment: With a real error it might help, in this case it doesn't seem to. weird. I would have expected to see status 404

Comment: I was wondering myself why the status wasn't 404 when pointing it to a non-existing file... anyway, I'll try this, and get back here to post the status of a real error. Thanks a lot for the info so far, I learned a lot!

Comment: same-origin errors often give a status of 0 and statusText of error

Comment: I have a real logged error now, it gives me: `{\&amp;#34;readyState\&amp;#34;:0,\&amp;#34;responseText\&amp;#34;:\&amp;#34;\&amp;#34;,\&amp;#34;status\&amp;#34;:0,\&amp;#34;statusText\&amp;#34;:\&amp;#34;error\&amp;#34;}` . Looks like it's also status 0... any idea what's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax call. Coz if your not setting this up and your expecting a json result, the result will be treated as 'string' by default.

Comment: The reason why I don't set the json-dataType, is to handle potential other echo's. That's why I check it for json, and if it's not, I store the string in my database (because it was probably an error). For example: the PHP-script is returning: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 50331648 bytes exhausted` . If I put `dataType: 'json'` in there, the ajax wouldn't be successful. Without json-dataType, it would be successful. My script would mark it as non-json, and store it appropriatly.

Comment: that's the reason why it keeps on giving you errors. Coz your AJAX call is expecting a string result and then your PHP code returns a JSON string (if successful). You can still return the error from PHP in json format so it will be uniform.

Something like this:

`echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Failed process'));`

Comment: So, what you are saying is, that it's always failing when successful? Because that's certainly not the case...